# Use Stimulus Controller in multiple places

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs, hotwire-rails, turbo-frames

I want to be able to use a Stimulus Controller in multiple places in a web app. I want do something like this:

```
<div data-controller="mycontroller">
  <OneComponent />
</div>

<SomeOtherComponent />

<div data-controller="mycontroller">
  <NewComponent />
</div>
```

But the controller just seem to connect to the first Component and not in the second. Is it possible to use it as I'm intending to?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code for your components?

Comment: Stimulus can definitely handle this (I have my own Stim controller that gets used as many as 10 times on one page). How do you know it only connects to one element?

Comment: Because in the `connect()` function just prints the first component.

Answer (score 1):

Stimulus controllers can be reused. See this sample.

Possible problems that may prevent this from working is if there is a JS error, or that you expect elements in nested components to be used in the parent component, if they have not been rendered yet.

```js
const application = Stimulus.Application.start()

application.register("hello", class extends Stimulus.Controller {
  connect() {
    console.log("connect to", this.element.getAttribute("data-language"))
  }
  
  static get targets() {
    return [ "name" ]
  }
  
  greet() {
    if (this.element.getAttribute("data-language") == "es-ES") {
      console.log(`¡Hola, ${this.nameTarget.value}!`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Hello, ${this.nameTarget.value}!`);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/stimulus/dist/stimulus.umd.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-controller="hello" data-language="en-US">
    <input data-hello-target="name" type="text" value="John">
    <button data-action="click->hello#greet">Greet</button>
  </div>
  
  <div data-controller="hello" data-language="es-ES">
    <input data-hello-target="name" type="text" value="Jose">
    <button data-action="click->hello#greet">Saudar</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about nested?